# Amazon DynamoDB - geographically distributed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to AWS. Sorry if my question is basic, got stuck with this term.

[AWS Global Infrastructure](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/) says "18 geographic Regions" -> Geographic term is used along with Regions, that makes sense.

[DynamoDB FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/) 3rd questions says, "Amazon DynamoDB stores **three geographically distributed replicas** of each table to enable high availability and data durability."

Here(**three geographically**) is it referring to Region or Availability Zones ? Bit confused. If it is Region, does it mean my data is going out of my country(if my country has only 1 Region).

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Geographically isolated in this documentation refers to Availability Zones and not Regions. As per AWS documentation when you create a table in one region, it's replicated in others zones to ensure the high availability. If you do some activity in the table it's updated in the replicas. The AZ's are interconnected with low latency networks.

> The data is stored on SSD disks and automatically replicated across
>   multiple Availability Zones in an AWS region, which brings the high
>   availability and your data is durable.

If you create a table in one region, the same table can be created in other regions also with same name.

If you want your table to be replicated in other regions you must enable the Cross-Region replication. For more details Refer

[DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html)

[All Things about DynamoDB](https://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2007/10/amazons_dynamo.html)

Comment: Yeah i guessed so, then what is the meaning of the number 3 ? there are few regions(Mumbai/Seoul) which has 2 AZs...

Comment: Maybe they keep three replicas, even though the AZ's are two.

Comment: I have heard it suggested by a non-authoritative source that in regions with fewer than 3 availability zones, there is a smaller, "hidden" availability zone that hosts the third cluster for internal services like DynamoDB and S3.  I have no idea whether this is accurate, but this seems like a reasonable conclusion where AWS promises 3 but there is only external evidence of 2.

Answer (score 2):

Almost every AWS service revolves around two things in availability: Multi AZ (multiple data centers in a single region) and Cross-Region (different geographic locations across globe) and so does the DynamoDB. By default AWS DynamoDB is a multi-AZ enabled service which means that your data is by default replicated across 3 data centers (minimum of 2 AZs) but for cross-region, you need to enable DynamoDB global tables (DynamoDB Streams).

Answer (score 0):

[Multi-Region Replication with DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GlobalTables.html)

DynamoDB global tables are geographically distributed. They provide a fully managed solution for deploying a multiregion, multi-active database. Like with every other geographically distributed database, GlobalTables comes with *ReplicationLatency*.

An important thing to note here is, DynamoDB does not offer cross-region strong consistency (this is in contrast with [CosmosDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels), a similar offering from Azure)

From AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/globaltables_HowItWorks.html):

> An application can read and write data to any replica table. If your
> application only uses eventually consistent reads and only issues
> reads against one AWS Region, it will work without any modification.
> However, if your application requires strongly consistent reads, it
> must perform all of its strongly consistent reads and writes in the
> same Region. DynamoDB does not support strongly consistent reads
> across Regions. Therefore, if you write to one Region and read from
> another Region, the read response might include stale data that
> doesn't reflect the results of recently completed writes in the other
> Region.

Also, global tables are not to be confused with global indexes. Global indexes get their name because they are used in fetching data across multiple DynamoDB partitions.

Answer (score 0):

> "Amazon DynamoDB stores three geographically distributed replicas of each table to enable high availability and data durability."

This is specifically referring to multi AZ structure of dynamo, this helps in achieving high availability of your table. eg. if one of availability zone is down you still will be able to access you table.

> To answer  "my data is going out of my country(if my country has only
> 1 Region)."

For multi region its not by default ON you need to use global tables and specify regions in which you want to replicate that means your data/table wont go in any other region till you specifically want it to be.

For more on global tables refer
https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/global-tables/